# Matching string from one file to another file and append the values

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have two text files with 350 m+ rows. Content of two text files are as follows:

```
file1:
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT
```

```
file2:
CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG -14.48
CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA -29.94
AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT -20.58
```

I would like to match the value of column 1 of file 2 and the string in file1 and append the value after `>` of file1 with file2 whenever there is a match.

The desired output is:

```
15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G    CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG    -14.48
15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G    CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA    -29.94
15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G    AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT    -20.58
```

Any suggestions would be helpful here.

Thanks

Comment: Your score tells you should know SO isn't a code-writing service.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Kindly add a code sample indicating what you have attempted as of yet.

Comment: Is the order or lines important? Because the fastest algorithm requires the files to be sorted.

Comment: I see a problem in file. All the 3 fasta sequences have same header/descriptions. ">15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G" .. I think as a first step you need to make them unique but you will know better. As has already been said, please show what you have tried and where it failed.

Comment: I tried to create a dictionary using `​dict = {}

with open("file1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        dict[str(key)] = val` but the values after '>' are not unique. I am trying to grep the strings where pattern is missing and then performing a string match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open( 'file2' ) as fin :
    data = { i.strip().split() for i in fin }

with open( 'file1' ) as fin :
    for line in fin :
        if line.startswith('>') :
            print line[1:].strip(),
        else :
            stripped = line.strip()
            print stripped, data[stripped]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from file1 and use it to process file2.

```
from io import StringIO

file1 = '''\
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA
>15_48499991_ENSG00000074803_C_G_G
AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT
'''

file2 = '''\
CCAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTG -14.48
CAATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGA -29.94
AATCGCTTTCAAGTTAGTGTGAT -20.58
'''

# Create a look-up table from first file.
map = {}
with StringIO(file1) as file:  # Open file1.
    for line in file:
        first = line.rstrip()[1:]  # Remove leading '>'.
        second = next(file).rstrip()
        map[second] = first

# Output matches in desired format.
with StringIO(file2) as file:  # Open file2.
    for line in file:
        first, second = line.split()
        print(f'{map[first]}    {first}    {second}')
```

Answer (score 0):

using bash/ **join**, assuming the delimiter in file2 is a tab

```
join -t $'\t' -1 2 -2 1 \
          <(cat file1 | paste - - | sort -t $'\t' -k2,2) \
          <(sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 file2)
```